# Space not being freed up on network drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-drive

I am using a network drive and I deleted a very large folder (around 30 GB). I did it by just right-clicking it and clicking "Delete". The drive has not shown any space being freed up at all and I can't find the file anywhere. What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried hitting F5 to refresh the window?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes, I have. I have also emptied my recycling bin.

Comment: That would probably reflect a problem with the network drive's driver or service.  You should provide as much detail as possible on what the server is and what client drivers are used.

Comment: Files deleted over the network shouldn't end up in your Recycle Bin.  Have you checked the drive space reported at the server itself and compared it to what you're seeing from your workstation?

Comment: if it is a NAS like QNap, it has a "Recycle" folder inside that you need to clear from the web interface

Comment: Are you running volume shadow copy on the network drive? If so it will retain the deleted files for a specified number of days. You may need to investigate this option